# Parse HTML structure using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is the structure of the HTML doc I need to parse (Refer UPDATE 3):

```
    <div id="txt_123_C01" style="position:absolute; left:5px; top:206px; width:532px; height:8912px;">
        <div class="Normal-P1">
        <span class="Normal-C2">Main title 1<br></span></div>
        <div class="Normal-P1">
        <span class="Normal-C3">Optional Subtitle<br></span></div>
        <div class="Normal-P1">
        <span class="Normal-C3">Second Optional Subtitle</span>
        <span class="Normal-C4">Text blurb 1.<br></span></div>
        <div class="Normal-P1">
        <span class="Normal-C4">Text blurb 2.<br></span></div>
        <div class="Normal-P1">
        <span class="Normal-C4">Text blurb 4.<br></span></div>
        <span class="Normal-C4"><br></span></div>
        <div class="Normal-P1">
        <span class="Normal-C3"><br></span></div>

    <div class="Normal-P1">
        <span class="Normal-C2">Main title 2<br></span></div>
        <div class="Normal-P1">
        <span class="Normal-C3">Subtitle 1</span>
        <span class="Normal-C4"> Other text blurb 1.<br></span></div>
        <div class="Normal-P1">
        <span class="Normal-C4"> Other text blurb 2.<br></span></div>
```

I want to generate a CSV that looks like this:

```
    Main Title     Optional Subtitle 1     Optional Subtitle 2        Text Blurb
    ----------     -------------------     -------------------       ------------------------     
    Main title 1   Optional Subtitle       Second Optional Subtitle   Text blurb1. Textblurb2. Text blurb 4.
    Main Title 2     Subtitle 1                                         Other text blurb 2.
```

I have tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'xml')
divText = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'Normal-P1'})
for item in divText:
    spanTitle = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'Normal-C2'})
    spanOptopnal = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'Normal-C3'})
```

However, this approach doesn't allow me to separate out the `Normal-P1` classes such that I go from `C2` to `C4` and then start again. The `C3` between the `C4` and the next `C2` doesn't always exist. In those cases, `C4`is the final tag before the next `C2`.

I have considered putting all `div`s in a list and then splitting them into sublists based on `C2` to process them. I am trying to figure out if there's a more elegant solution using bs4.

UPDATE 1

Getting back to this after a while. I just reviewed my output using the answer below and see an issue.

Looking at

```
   titles = soup.select(".Normal-P1 .Normal-C2")
   for entry in titles:
            print "entry:",entry
            parent = entry.parent
            print "parent: ",parent
            subtitles = [
                subtitle.text for subtitle in
                parent.select(' ~ .Normal-P1 .Normal-C3')
            ]
            print "subtitles:",subtitles
```

I find `subtitles` to contain results from outside the parent (i.e., all `titles`). The output looks like this:

```
entry: <span class="Normal-C2">Main title 1<br/></span>
parent:  <div class="Normal-P1">
<span class="Normal-C2">Main title 1<br/></span></div>
subtitles: [Optional Subtitle,Second Optional Subtitle,Subtitle 1]


entry: <span class="Normal-C2">Main title 2<br/></span>
parent:  <div class="Normal-P1">
<span class="Normal-C2">Main title 2<br/></span></div>
subtitles: [Subtitle 1]
```

UPDATE 2

`parent.select(" ~ .Normal-P1 .Normal-C3")` appears to be causing the issue.

The issue is here in the HTML provided in the solution: `<span class="Normal-C4"><br></span> </div>`. It's missing `<div class="Normal-P1">` and a closing `</div>` at the end. On making these changes, I see the same issue (all subtitles in the document showing up for an entry) in this sample HTML as well.

I double-checked the indentation and that looks ok to me. What am I doing incorrectly?

UPDATE 3

This is the complete HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="txt_123_C01" style="position:absolute; left:5px; top:206px; width:532px; height:8912px;">
    <div class="Normal-P1">
      <span class="Normal-C2">Main title 1<br></span>
    </div>
    <div class="Normal-P1">
      <span class="Normal-C3">Optional Subtitle<br></span>
    </div>
    <div class="Normal-P1">
      <span class="Normal-C3">Second Optional Subtitle</span>
      <span class="Normal-C4">Text blurb 1.<br></span>
    </div>
    <div class="Normal-P1">
      <span class="Normal-C4">Text blurb 2.<br></span>
    </div>
    <div class="Normal-P1">
      <span class="Normal-C4">Text blurb 4.<br></span>
    </div>
    <div class="Normal-P1">
    <span class="Normal-C4"><br></span>
  </div>
  <div class="Normal-P1">
    <span class="Normal-C3"><br></span>
  </div>

  <div class="Normal-P1">
    <span class="Normal-C2">Main title 2<br></span>
  </div>
  <div class="Normal-P1">
    <span class="Normal-C3">New Subtitle 1</span>
    <span class="Normal-C4"> Other text blurb 1.<br></span>
  </div>
  <div class="Normal-P1">
    <span class="Normal-C4"> Other text blurb 2.<br></span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the output I see

```
    entry: <span class="Normal-C2">Main title 1<br/></span>
    parent:  <div class="Normal-P1">

<span class="Normal-C2">Main title 1<br/></span>

    </div>
    subtitle: <span class="Normal-C3">Optional Subtitle<br/></span>
    subtitle: <span class="Normal-C3">Second Optional Subtitle</span>
    subtitle: <span class="Normal-C3"><br/></span>
    subtitle: <span class="Normal-C3">New Subtitle 1</span>
    entry: <span class="Normal-C2">Main title 2<br/></span>
    parent:  <div class="Normal-P1">
    <span class="Normal-C2">Main title 2<br/></span>
    </div>
    subtitle: <span class="Normal-C3">New Subtitle 1</span>
```

This is my code at present:

```
file = filepath + "test-page.html"
parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
pageFile = codecs.open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
pageRaw = pageFile.read()
page = parser.unescape(pageRaw)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
titles = soup.select(".Normal-P1 .Normal-C2")

for entry in titles:
    print "entry:",entry
    parent = entry.parent
    print "parent: ",parent

    for subtitle in parent.select(" ~ .Normal-P1 .Normal-C3"):
        print "subtitle:", subtitle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS Selectors, you're going to want to target the class names, which you do via `.Class-Name` and siblings, which is via `ParentTag ~ .Child-Class`

[Mozillas MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) have a good little primer on them.

python file:

```
import bs4
import csv

entries = []

with open("example.html", "r") as page:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

    # CSS Selectors for items with class Normal-P1 followed by
    # Normal-C2
    titles = soup.select(".Normal-P1 .Normal-C2")

    for entry in titles:
        entry_dict = {
            'Main Title': '',
            'Optional Subtitle 1': '',
            'Optional Subtitle 2': '',
            'Text Blurb': ''
        }
        parent = entry.parent

        entry_dict['Main Title'] = entry.text

        subtitles = [
            subtitle.text for subtitle in
            parent.select(' ~ .Normal-P1 .Normal-C3')
            # CSS Selector for siblings of the same parent element that have
            # classes Normal-P1 followed by Normal-C3
        ]
        try:
            entry_dict['Optional Subtitle 1'] = subtitles[0]
            entry_dict['Optional Subtitle 2'] = subtitles[1]
        except IndexError:
            pass

        entry_dict['Text Blurb'] = ' '.join(
            blurb.text for blurb in
            parent.select(' ~ .Normal-P1 .Normal-C4')
            # CSS Selector for siblings of the same parent element that have
            # classes Normal-P1 followed by Normal-C4
        )

        entries.append(entry_dict)

    with open('out.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = [
            'Main Title',
            'Optional Subtitle 1',
            'Optional Subtitle 2',
            'Text Blurb'
        ]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(
            csv_file,
            fieldnames=fieldnames,
            quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
        )
        writer.writeheader()
        for entry in entries:
            writer.writerow(entry)
```

html file used:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="txt_123_C01" style="position:absolute; left:5px; top:206px; width:532px; height:8912px;">
    <div class="Normal-P1">
      <span class="Normal-C2">Main title 1<br></span>
    </div>
    <div class="Normal-P1">
      <span class="Normal-C3">Optional Subtitle<br></span>
    </div>
    <div class="Normal-P1">
      <span class="Normal-C3">Second Optional Subtitle</span>
      <span class="Normal-C4">Text blurb 1.<br></span>
    </div>
    <div class="Normal-P1">
      <span class="Normal-C4">Text blurb 2.<br></span>
    </div>
    <div class="Normal-P1">
      <span class="Normal-C4">Text blurb 4.<br></span>
    </div>
    <span class="Normal-C4"><br></span>
  </div>
  <div class="Normal-P1">
    <span class="Normal-C3"><br></span>
  </div>

  <div class="Normal-P1">
    <span class="Normal-C2">Main title 2<br></span>
  </div>
  <div class="Normal-P1">
    <span class="Normal-C3">Subtitle 1</span>
    <span class="Normal-C4"> Other text blurb 1.<br></span>
  </div>
  <div class="Normal-P1">
    <span class="Normal-C4"> Other text blurb 2.<br></span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

csv output:

```
"Main Title","Optional Subtitle 1","Optional Subtitle 2","Text Blurb"

"Main title 1","Optional Subtitle","Second Optional Subtitle","Text blurb 1. Text blurb 2. Text blurb 4."

"Main title 2","Subtitle 1",""," Other text blurb 1.  Other text blurb 2."
```

edit:
I'm not sure what you're doing with HTMLParser but there's no need for that. BeautifulSoup handles reading files just fine.

```
import bs4
import codecs


with codecs.open("example.html", "r", encoding='utf-8') as page:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

    # CSS Selectors for items with class Normal-P1 followed by
    # Normal-C2
    titles = soup.select(".Normal-P1 .Normal-C2")

    for entry in titles:
        print("entry: ", entry.text)
        parent = entry.parent
        print("parent:", parent)

        subtitles = [
            subtitle.text for subtitle in
            parent.select(' ~ .Normal-P1 .Normal-C3')
            # CSS Selector for siblings of the same parent element that have
            # classes Normal-P1 followed by Normal-C3
        ]
        try:
            print("subtitle: ", subtitles[0])
            print('subtitle: ', subtitles[1])
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

output

```
entry:  Main title 1
parent: <div class="Normal-P1">
<span class="Normal-C2">Main title 1<br/></span>
</div>
subtitle:  Optional Subtitle
subtitle:  Second Optional Subtitle
entry:  Main title 2
parent: <div class="Normal-P1">
<span class="Normal-C2">Main title 2<br/></span>
</div>
subtitle:  Subtitle 1
```

Comment: I don't see any output when I do `titles = soup.select(".Normal-P1 .Normal-C2")
print "titles: ", titles`. The HTML structure is 

`<html lang="en">
<body>
<center>
<div>
<div id="txt_123_C01">`

Is the structure responsible for me not seeing any results. Also, I have had to do:

`pageFile = codecs.open(file, 'r')
page = pageFile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'xml')
titles = soup.select(".Normal-P1 .Normal-C2")
print "titles: ", titles`

Comment: Make sure you're using `lxml` instead of `xml` for the second arg of `bs4.BeautifulSoup()`

Comment: yep! that did it

Comment: You have the lines below the try/except block indented, which puts them in the scope for the except portion. Move the lines after `pass` back a level.

Comment: `parent.select(" ~ .Normal-P1 .Normal-C3")` appears to be causing the issue. The results aren't limited to each `subtitle`

Comment: The issue is here in the HTML you provided:
`<span class="Normal-C4"><br></span>
  </div>`
It's missing `<div class="Normal-P1">` and a closing `</div>` at the end. On making these changes, I see the same issue (all `subtitles` in the document showing up for an entry) in this sample HTML as well.

Comment: Could really use some help here. Can someone please guide me towards a solution? I tried a bunch of things using CSS selectors but none of them give me the output I want.

Comment: You need to provide a complete html example

Comment: Thank you for the response. I provided the complete HTML in update 3

Comment: need your help. I am stuck here and cannot figure out a solution

Comment: The solution I provided appears to work fine even with your changes to the HTML, so I'm not sure of your issue.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have added the relevant code and output to the question. Please review.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using HTMLparser, but it looks like you're using python 2.7. If at all possible I'd suggest upgrading to python 3.7. I've edited my answer to show your existing code giving the expected output

Comment: The HTML parser helps with encoding some characters in the text. I'd prefer using 2.7 if I can help it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186274/discussion-between-cssko-and-kurious).